# LWJGL - Frame Buffer Textures

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I am working on a Frame Buffer Object in lwjgl to store a single texture.  I have 2 issues at present, the first issue being is that the texture in the frame buffer does not seem to be clearing before rendering the next frame as shown below (is ghosting the correct term?):

[FrameBuffer Texture result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OajXn.png)

`glCheckFrameBufferStatus` returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE for this FBO.

Each frame the renderer calls:

```
GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

before any rendering happens at all  (its the first call before shaders are executed) so i am not sure why its behaving this way.

The texture for the framebuffer is created as follows:

```
private int createTexAttachment()
    {
        int texture = GL11.glGenTextures();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL30.GL_RGB32F, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_FLOAT, (FloatBuffer)(null));
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        GL32.glFramebufferTexture(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, texture, 0);

        return texture;
    }
```

When the renderer reaches the FBO render pass it binds the FBO like so:

```
public void bind()
    {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        //ensure an unbound texture
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    }
```

and it is then unbound after the render pass with:

```
public void unbind()
    {
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    }
```

My second issue is, I am attempting to write the world space position of each fragment in the render to the texture, but from the above image it can be seen it is not working, below are the Vertex and Fragment shaders I use for this pass:

```
//vertex shader
#version 140

in vec3 position;

out vec4 worldSpacePosition;

uniform mat4 projMatrix;    //projection matrix
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;    //camera view matrix
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;   //transformation (model) matrix

void main(void)
{
    vec4 worldPos = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec4 pos = projMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    gl_Position = pos;
    worldSpacePosition = worldPos;
}

//fragment shader
#version 140

in vec4 worldSpacePosition;

out vec4 out_colour;

void main(void)
{
    out_colour = worldSpacePosition;
}
```

The ultimate goal is to sample a given pixel of the FBO texture (using glReadPixels) to extract its position in the world.  I have tried to achieve this with `GL11.glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL30.GL_RGB32F, GL11.GL_FLOAT, fb);` which produces xyz/rgb values of 0,0,0 regardless of which pixel is sampled, and also `GL11.glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_FLOAT, fb);` which provides xyz/rgb values between 0 and 1, which is better than 0's, but still not the desired result.

I have also discovered that it is not performing a depth test when rendering through this FBO pass, so i am will try and find out why.

IF anyone might have any suggestions why my FBO texture is ghosting and how to store the xyz position of the fragment into the rgb channel of the FBO texture properly I would be grateful if you could please help :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

About issue 1 (clearing): Do you bind the framebuffer before calling `glClear`? The clearing operation is always performed on the currently bound framebuffer (or the backbuffer when no FBO is bound).

About isse 2: Your texture has the format `GL_RGBA`, which is a 8bit normalized format which only allows to store values between 0 and 1. In addition, your internal format (`GL_RGB`) does not fit to your format (`GL_RGBA`). Either you want four channels or three, but they have to be compatible.

If you want to store world space position which are most probably not just between 0 and 1 you'll have to use a floating point texture (and more bits per channel). `GL_RGB32F` or `GL_RGBA32F` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I recalled the clear after the FBO is bound! i'll definately remember that one.

as for using GL_RGB32F, I set internal format to GL_RGB32F and the format to GL_RGB32F and the resulting rendered image is completely black

`GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL30.GL_RGB32F, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL30.GL_RGB32F, GL11.GL_FLOAT, (FloatBuffer)(null));`

Comment: Please look at the documentation! Only the internal format can be a sized format, the format has to be `GL_RGB`. Outputting the world space position as color has some problems. For example, negative position will be black. Everything larger than 1 will be full saturated. Without knowing your scene and the values you are writing to the texture, black could be correct or not.

Comment: I am trying to read the world space of a given pixel using glReadPixels from the aforementioned texture, but despite storing the texture as GLRGB32F the resulting values are between 0 and 1 if I read with GLRGB and always 0 when i read with GLRGB32F.  I am not concerned with its visual representation, I only used it for visual debugging reasons.  I have spent hours reading through documentation, but understanding through reading documentation is not my strong suit, I learn through demonstration.

Comment: Could you update your question with the current state of the code?

Comment: Done, I noticed it is not using depth test and some objects are appearing in front of others, so I will try and figure out why

Comment: Depth testing is only working when the FBO has a depth attachment.

Comment: I have a depth attachment, but I stopped using it because it renders completely red for some reason.

i used 'GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT' for internal format and format as the tutorial I was following had done, as well as configuring the 'MAG' and 'MIN' filters to 'GL_LINEAR', and 'GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T' and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` to `GL_REPEAT` and `glFrameBufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTHATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);`, and yes the depth buffer bit is cleared before the FBO is rendered to